# Sharing unpublished Gmail add-on with other people

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, google-workspace, google-apps-marketplace

guys!

I developed a gmail add-on and I am still testing it. The plan is to publish the add-on later.
What is the best way to share this add-on with my beta-testers?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a domain where you have beta-testers?

Comment: no, I intended to let them try on their private accounts

Answer (score 1):

Share your script with your beta-testers and tell them to:

## [Install the unpublished Add-On](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/cats-quickstart#step_3_install_the_unpublished_add-on)

### Here's how fast it is:

[image]

### In the pop up, they should create a new deployment and finally they should install the add-on:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, test configurations are not applicable to GMail Add-ons. Currently, they only work with Editor Add-ons.

Comment: Then you can go for the first option, sharing the script with them, and telling them how to install it.